# Barbecue barcode generator does not show barcode number with a web app

Tags: java, spring, web, barcode

I tried with Barbecue Barcode generator in a stand alone Java application and was able to print barcodes with barcode number as displayed in the image.

[image]

But when I execute same method from spring web application, the generated barcodes does not show the barcode number as in below image. I am using same file path to save images and have full rw permissions to the directory. Do you have any clue on this, Thanks

[image]

I am using below code snippet

```
barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128A(barcode_Id);
File f = new File("/opt/rd/barcode/"+barcode_Id+".png");
BarcodeImageHandler.savePNG(barcode, f);
```

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem. Have you come across a solution?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue

Comment: I am also facing this issue, how you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue in Grails setting a font for my barcode and overwriting the **calculateSize()** method in **Barcode**:

```
private Dimension calculateSize(){
    Dimension d = new Dimension();
    if(EnvironmentFactory.getEnvironment() instanceof HeadlessEnvironment)
    try
    {

        if(font == null)
        {
            d = draw(new SizingOutput(font, getForeground(), getBackground()), 0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
        } else
        {
            java.awt.FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(font);
            d = draw(new SizingOutput(font, fontMetrics, getForeground(), getBackground()), 0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
        }
    }
    catch(OutputException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    else
    try
    {
        java.awt.FontMetrics fontMetrics = null;
        if(font != null)
        fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(font);
        d = draw(new SizingOutput(font, fontMetrics, getForeground(), getBackground()), 0, 0, barWidth, barHeight);
    }
    catch(OutputException e) { }
    return d;
}
```

[This thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/barbecue/discussion/266281/thread/786e8818) in sourceforge can shed some more light on this issue.

Comment: How to do this with maven project ?